# How to check mouse click position is on required application?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I know the mouse click position using API `GetCursorPos` and the handle of application (`HWND`).

How can I check mouse click position is on this application?

My view:

- Get the bounding box of application from its handle. (`GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);`)
- Check cursor position lies in this bounding box. (`PtInRect(&rect, p)`)

This is not working if windows are overlapping.

Comment: No it won't if another window is overlapping it.

Comment: @iBug yes that is the problem with this.

Comment: Look at [`WindowFromPoint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558.aspx) to get the `HWND` that is underneath the mouse cursor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Used same api for the answer. Added the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know the handle of targeted screen handle and click cursor position:

```
// hWnd : Already known windows handle

GetCursorPos(&p);
HWND hWndFromPoint = WindowFromPoint(p);

// If the handle got from click point is child of the desire window means it is clicked on the desire window itself.
if (IsChild(hWnd, hWndFromPoint))
{
    // Do something on Mouse click 
}
```